# using GridView to display data in fixed row positions

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Good day gurus!

I don't know if this is very easy to do but I am still learning ASP.NET and this seems to be a very challenging task for me. Here's what I'm trying to do...

I'm trying to display a table, just like this:

[image]

I also need the rows' positions to be fixed. 
ie. Light, (Adjust1/Adjust2: if it's not null), Nail, Sponge, Rod, Prod.Cost, etc.

And here's the content of the SQL database from which I'll fetch the data:

[image]

Shed some light please. Throw topics I need to research on, links, tutorials, etc. It would be very helpful to my learning.

Thank you for sharing your time and knowledge,

Pod Mays

PS: I'm also in the process of searching for other features like putting the Remarks when a cell is highlighted and hiding the Adjust columns when they're NULL.

Comment: Gridview will not display data as shown in the picture.You have to manually create table structure

Comment: does that mean I have to bound Labels inside a table for each cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try starting here ..

http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/5-working-with-data